# Face detection using AForge.NET and c# ( draw rectangle over face )

Tags: c#, aforge

I'm trying to do face detection in c# with Neural networks and some basic image preprocessing.
With AForge.NET I created NN and successfully trained it for detection is an image face or non-face. For faster learning I resized images to 20x20. Basically NN returns "1" for face otherwise "0". This works fine with image that contains extracted face but I want to apply it on new frame from webCam with my face and some background. 
My issue is how to search through this frame and implement NN classifier on all 20x20 rectangles in my 640x480 image from webCam to find localization of face.

Answer (score 0):

Well if the camera is static, then the background is no information.
Create a bitmap of it, then only if your webcams shows something that isnt like that
then use for your facial detection.
Overall a blob filter might help there to get the center, and then next try your algorythm

or do a circle detection, people usually have two eyes near each other.
then after that from there start your NN net.